# Why does python3 take twice as long as python2 to load?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm supporting a project on both python2 and python3, and noticed that the python3 interpreter is taking almost 3 times as long to load as the python2 interpreter.

(Running on Arch Linux)

```
$ cat hello.py
print('Hello World!')
$ python -V
Python 3.4.2
$ time python hello.py
Hello World!

real    0m1.561s
user    0m1.290s
sys     0m0.110s
$ python2 -V
Python 2.7.9
$ time python2 hello.py
Hello World!

real    0m0.613s
user    0m0.513s
sys     0m0.070s
```

And once more with no code:

```
$ rm foo ; touch foo ; time python foo ; time python2 foo

real    0m1.710s
user    0m1.297s
sys     0m0.103s

real    0m1.040s
user    0m0.667s
sys     0m0.100s
$ echo $PYTHONSTARTUP

$ rm foo ; touch foo ; time python -B foo ; time python2 -B foo

real    0m1.554s
user    0m1.117s
sys     0m0.123s

real    0m0.678s
user    0m0.557s
sys     0m0.090s
```

What is going on here?

Comment: What OS?  What specific versions of python2.x and python3.x are you running?  I know that earlier python3.x versions were mostly "get the features implemented -- don't worry about performance" revisions.  IIRC Starting at python3.3 I think the performance (for most things) started to get close to python2.x's...

Comment: what, exactly, is your script doing? I'm guessing it has something to do with the string types you're using in each script. Try creating an empty python file, and running the same test. I got an outlier of 2 times slower for my first py3 test. Then they were exactly the same.

Comment: How do you know those times are "load" times?  It could also be the "unload" that's taking extra time. :)

Comment: You should make more than one measurement...

Comment: Josh: This script is a Hello World script. I can add further stripped down example, but that's not going to change much.

Comment: It most certainly is going to change much. Strings are handled very differently between python2 and python3. If you're trying to measure the load time of the interpreter, then make sure there's no code to execute - otherwise you're measuring a program, not the interpreter.

Comment: Regardless - I can not replicate your variations. I'm getting consistent measurements of "0m0.02x" for py2 and py3 just doing a print('Hello World!'). Not sure how you're seeing half to full seconds. Show your script or this discussion is pointless.

Comment: selbie: $ echo "import time
> 
> print(time.clock())" > foobar ; time python foobar; time python2 foobar
1.423577

real    0m2.052s
user    0m1.283s
sys     0m0.263s
0.546323

real    0m0.853s
user    0m0.467s
sys     0m0.170s

Illustrates that the vast majority of the time python spends running is during it's "loading" phase.

Comment: Josh: updated question for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling "[local site libraries](http://ztomasze.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/a-quick-fix-to-improve-python3-startup.html)" by passing `-S` to python.  Passing this has sped things up noticeably for me when I've been playing with slower ARM boxes.  For example, I get:

```
time python3 -S -c pass
```

running in about 0.076 seconds, wall clock time, while a vanilla:

```
time python3 -c pass
```

takes 0.247 seconds.  Passing this options to python2 results in a similar speedup for me under various distributions, so even this doesn't explain the disparity—just a way to work around some of it!

*Hope you don't mind me resurrecting this thread; google pointed me at this and I wanted to get a useful answer.*

Answer (score 0):

The startup time you're seeing is significantly different to what I can see on my system:

```
$ touch py
$ python3 py
$ time python3 py

real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.019s
sys 0m0.006s

$ python3 -V
Python 3.4.2

$ time python py

real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.013s
sys 0m0.008s

$ python -V
Python 2.7.8
```

I see a marginal increase with python3, but nothing like the 1 second increase that you are seeing. There are probably 2 reasons that I can think of that may be causing the difference. The first is that you may have a python startup file executing on interpreter load.

```
$ echo $PYTHONSTARTUP
~/.pythonrc
```

Check to see if you have a startup file loaded for python3 but not for python2.

Also, try running your test without writing bytecode:

```
time python -B foo
```

This is probably an environment issue local to your setup rather than a major difference between versions of the interpreter.

Comment: I don't have a startup file.  I'll add my non-bytecode results to my question.  I'm using an old 600 Mhz machine as my testbed, which accounts for the low speed, but shouldn't result in such a large difference in load times.